# Perl strings encode utf 8

Tags: string, perl, utf-8, encode

I am reading about Perl's `Encode` and utf8.

The doc says:

> $octets = encode_utf8($string);
>
> Equivalent to
>
> $octets = encode("utf8", $string) .
>
> The characters in   $string are encoded in Perl's internal format, and
>   the result is returned as a sequence of   octets.

I have no idea what this means. Isn't a string in Perl a sequence of octets (i.e. bytes) anyway?

So what is the difference between:

`$string` and `$octets`?

Answer (score 4):

No, a string in Perl is a sequence of *characters*, not necessarily octets. The `chr` and `ord` functions (for transforming between integers and single characters), to name two, can deal with integer values larger than 255. For example

```
$string = "\x{0421}\x{041F}";
print ord($_)," " for split //, $string;
```

outputs

```
1057 1055
```

When a string is written to a terminal, file, or other output stream, the device receiving the string usually requires and expects bytes, however, so this is where encoding comes in. As you have seen, UTF-8 is a scheme for encoding single value in the range 0x7F-0x10FFFF into multiple bytes.

```
$octets = Encode::encode("utf-8", "\x{0421}\x{041F}");
print ord($_)," " for split //, $octets;
```

Now the output is

```
208 161 208 159
```

and suitable to be stored on a filesystem.

Internally, `perl` (in all lower case, this refers to the executable implementation of Perl, the programming language specification) often uses UTF-8 to represent strings with "wide" characters, but this is not something you would every normally have to worry about.

Comment: What does `\x{0421}` mean?

Comment: `\x{0421}` is the character whose encoding is the hex number 0x421. That's apparently 'CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES' (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/421)

Comment: So why not `decode`  instead of encode here to decode into Perl characters?

Comment: You'll use `decode` when you process encoded input, say, reading from a UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: When you say that Perl stores the data as characters and not bytes don't you mean UTF-8 characters?Could you please help me clear this out?

Comment: "UTF-8 characters" isn't a thing. There are Unicode code points (from 0-0x10FFFF) and there is a UTF-8 encoding that represents all Unicode code points as one or more octets (bytes). When you use `substr`, `chop`, `split`, regular expressions, or any other feature of Perl that acts on a string, you are dealing with characters.

Comment: ... and you don't have to care whether those characters originally came from a UTF-8 or latin-1 or whatever source.